# security for php script on isset function and operator [? :]

Tags: php, security, operator-keyword, isset

the guru say : there is a trouble of security on that code.
the guru say : the attacker can conceal the fact that a variable name of $search is manipulated.

```
<?php
$search = (isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '');
?>
```

my question:
what's the way of the attacker attack this code on that a variable name of $search?

Comment: It all depends on what is going to be done with `$search`

Answer (score 2):

Your guru is not a guru at all (or you didn't understand what they originally mean).

It's just a line of code that cannot be vulnerable by itself.